# crosstalk and plotly - ggplotly does not accept shareddata-object

Tags: r, plotly, htmlwidgets

I've been trying to generate interactive linked visualizations with by use of the plotly and crosstalk libraries. As shown in the example below, it seems to be possible to pass ggplot2 a 'shared Dataframe'-Object in order to generate linked views with ggplotly(). When i try to run this example i get the following error-message:

**Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class SharedData/R6**

I'm using the current versions of ggplot2 (v. 2.2.1) and plotly (4.5.6). What can cause this error?

Thx for help!

The example which i'm trying to replicate can be found here:

https://cpsievert.github.io/plotly_book/linking-animated-views.html

```
library(gapminder)
library(crosstalk)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

g <- crosstalk::SharedData$new(gapminder, ~continent)

gg <- ggplot(g, aes(gdpPercap, lifeExp, color = continent, frame = year)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = pop, ids = country)) +
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE, method = "lm") +
  scale_x_log10()
  ggplotly(gg) %>% 
  highlight("plotly_hover")

  Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class SharedData/R6
```

Comment: You'd need to install the dev version `devtools::install_github("ropensci/plotly")`. Restart R if you face installation issues.

Comment: If you face an issue like I did after `ggplotly(gg)` - `Error: No graphics device is currently open and no cairo or bitmap device is available.`, then run `quartz()` before `ggplotly(gg)`

Comment: The working packages versions I used : plotly 4.5.6.9000, ggplot2 2.2.1.9000

Comment: Thanks a lot! With the plotly development version, ggplot does now accept the shareddata-object. However, when i call ggplotly in the next step i get a further Error message: **Error in ggfun("create_layout")(plot$facet, plot$coordinates): unused argument (plot$coordinates)**

Comment: No idea. I suggest you raise an issue @ https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues with your environment details.

Comment: it is working now - after reinstalling ggplot2 2.2.1.9000. Thanks again for your help!